# 2-3-4 tree height

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

I observed that the height of a 2-3-4 tree can be different depending of the order of insertion of nodes.

e.g. 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 will yield a tree of height 2

While inserting in this order:

e.g. 1, 5, 10, 2, 3, 8, 9, 4, 7, 8 will yield a tree of height 1

Is this a normal property of a 2-3-4 tree? Inserting nodes in sequence will yield a very imbalanced tree in that case. I thought 2-3-4 trees should be balanced trees?

Comment: 2-3-4 trees, like most balanced tree structures, will differ slightly in height depending on insertion order as you say, but should remain $O(\log n)$ for all operations.  However, a height 1 2-3-4 tree should have at most 7 entries, so I believe you have a mistake in your construction.

Comment: Hi monteiroadel, and welcome to scicomp!  We strongly discourage posting the exact same question on multiple Stack Exchange websites.  If you have a related question which has a computational emphasis on it, please feel free to modify your question.  Otherwise, I recommend removing this post and keep the other (especially since you've already received answers on the other site).